# Disponibilizar um ficheiro para download numa API que retorna JSON

Tags: java, json, arquivo, tomcat, download

Olá,

Estou a desenvolver uma API em Java. É basicamente, uma servlet java que retorna conteúdo em json (application/json). Com um servidor tomcat.
Um dos campos de resposta é suposto ser um link para o download de um ficheiro .txt.

Não sei como fazer. Alguma dica?

Escrever no sistema de ficheiros a cada request parece me assassino, mesmo tendo algum cron para limpar a diretorias com os ficheiros.

Alguma forma de dar um link temporário só enquanto aquele pedido por um periodo sem guardar no sistema de ficheiros?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma de fazer isso é utilizando um serviço de storage, como o do firebase por exemplo e vai funcionar da seguinte forma.
Voce vai configurar a API no seu projeto e vai subir o arquivo no storage do firebase. Quando vc terminar de subir, ele vai retornar um link para acesso do arquivo como resposta. dai então você armazena o link e utiliza como quiser.